# Term, blend-word, or metaphor for being social but with boundaries

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, metaphors, portmanteau-words

I'm looking for a term, word or metaphor for being social but within rules or boundaries.

I don't like the word *privacy* as it has a negative connotation. I think the word *social* is overused or misunderstood, especially in the online realm. I assume real social interactions operate on trust and that certain behavioral rules must be followed. But doing things together bonds people, and they learn more about each other. *Etiquette* is too stodgy and doesn't encompass all that I am trying to say.

Any thoughts on how to combine all of these ideas into one word, a blend-word, or a metaphor, please?

Comment: Can you give a pseudo sentance where you'd like to use this word? Just put [x] where you'd like the word to go.

Comment: What do you mean 'within rules or boundaries'? What would being social _outside_ of those rules or boundaries be? How are privacy and etiquette in the same camp with respect to 'social'? This seems underspecified. Can you give a lot more (in your question about what you really mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for might be *conventional*. It means something like '(given to) behavior bounded by convention'.

It's not at all stodge; the fact that *conventional* is often used to condemn obsolete past conventions doesn't mean that it's lost its other, more precise, and less politically correct sense.

Conventions, especially [tacit conventions like grammar](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/the_good_word/2012/05/steven_pinker_on_the_false_fronts_in_the_language_wars_.single.html), are simply common solutions to common problems, like which side of the road to drive on. It's not **stodgy**, within the meaning of the act, to drive on the left in the UK but on the right in the US. Doing otherwise, in fact, is both illegal and dangerous. Being conventional just means observing boundaries like we all do.

Comment: Conventional is an interesting concept, John. Sort of like a double yellow line that runs between opposite lanes of a highway. We observe those lines as a matter of convention without even thinking about it really (tacit). However, online networks have people thinking about those double yellow lines differently than before.

Answer (score 2):

I think the concepts closest to what you mean are those of being *tactful* and of being *appropriate*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Thoughtful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thoughtful)*, "Demonstrating kindness or consideration for others" may be along the lines of what is sought.  There are numerous synonyms or related words that provide quite a variety of senses; *eg [sensible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sensible)* for "Acting with or showing good sense; able to make good judgements based on reason", *[deliberate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deliberate)* for "Formed with deliberation; well-advised; carefully considered; not sudden or rash", *[circumspect](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/circumspect)* for "Carefully aware of all circumstances; considerate of all that is pertinent", and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

[*Polite*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polite), "Showing good manners toward others, as in behavior, speech, etc.; courteous; civil: a polite reply;" or perhaps [*cordial*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cordial?__utma=1.1971460336.1336408129.1339093236.1339093384.10&__utmb=1.2.10.1339093384&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1337882817.3.3.utmcsr=dictionary.reference.com%7Cutmccn=%28referral%29%7Cutmcmd=referral%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29%7Cutmcct=/browse/drunk&__utmv=-&__utmk=46800679), "courteous and gracious; friendly; warm: a cordial reception."

Comment: I really like your two suggestions: _polite and cordial_. Together, they seem a good fit for the O.P.'s request.

Answer (score 0):

*Proper* might be a good fit. It is [defined as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/proper_2) "showing standards of behavior that are socially and morally acceptable."

Also if you are [*mannerly*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mannerly) or [*well-mannered*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well-mannered) you act with politeness and are socially correct in your behavior.

All of these words have an aspect of conforming to a social standard or boundaries of social behavior.